# Parsing text file into a Data Frame

Tags: regex, r, parsing

I have a text file which has information, like so:

```
product/productId: B000GKXY4S
product/title: Crazy Shape Scissor Set
product/price: unknown
review/userId: A1QA985ULVCQOB
review/profileName: Carleen M. Amadio "Lady Dragonfly"
review/helpfulness: 2/2
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1314057600
review/summary: Fun for adults too!
review/text: I really enjoy these scissors for my inspiration books that I am making (like collage, but in books) and using these different textures these give is just wonderful, makes a great statement with the pictures and sayings. Want more, perfect for any need you have even for gifts as well. Pretty cool!

product/productId: B000GKXY4S
product/title: Crazy Shape Scissor Set
product/price: unknown
review/userId: ALCX2ELNHLQA7
review/profileName: Barbara
review/helpfulness: 0/0
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1328659200
review/summary: Making the cut!
review/text: Looked all over in art supply and other stores for "crazy cutting" scissors for my 4-year old grandson. These are exactly what I was looking for - fun, very well made, metal rather than plastic blades (so they actually do a good job of cutting paper), safe ("blunt") ends, etc. (These really are for age 4 and up, not younger.) Very high quality. Very pleased with the product.
```

I want to parse this into a dataframe with the productID, title, price.. as columns and the data as the rows. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty approach:

```
mytable <- read.table(text=mytxt, sep = ":")
mytable$id <- rep(1:2, each = 10)
res <- reshape(mytable, direction = "wide", timevar = "V1", idvar = "id")
```

There will be issues if there are other colons in the data.  Also assumes that there is an equal number (10) of variables for each case.  All